# Most efficient way to read list of values from Hazelcast Map

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast as a cache and want to read a list of 50 items from a single map. Currently we are seeing quite a long delay reading this list ~20ms. Reading a single entry is extremely quick but it seems this is scaling quite badly. I have tried using the Imap methods of

- .getAll(setOfKeys)
- Iterating the list and calling .get(singleKey) for each one
- Iterating the list and calling .getAsync(singleKey) and then iterating the list of futures getting them

Is there a better way to do this or do I need to rethink the way we are caching/using Hazelcast to reduce the get call on the map to a single call somehow.

Few bits of additional info

- The total number of items in the map is ~35,000
- The size of all items is ~350MB with each entry being ~10kb
- I am running this embedded into the JVM in a Spring Boot application on my local machine
- The call on HazelcastInstance.getMap(mapName) is taking less than 1ms

Comment: If I understand this correct, values are stored independently against their respective keys (one key: one value) and you are trying to retrieve a bunch of them returned in a List?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a lot on the exact setup, but from your question, it looks as you didn't try `entrySet()`.

I believe that would be the fastest.